# Rails Generate Multiple Conditions Security Concern

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am creating a scope block that will generate something along the lines of

```
Letter.join(:people).where("people.lastname = ? OR people.lastname = ?", 'Carter', 'Testname')
```

I want to be able to make my query dynamic, however, so you could send in any number of names to pull in as results

```
Letter.find_person(['Carter', 'Testname'])
```

I have figured out two ways to get the desired query, but I am not sure that either of them are very secure.  I wanted to use the question mark syntax above but I am having trouble figuring out how to finagle it.

1:

```
peopleArray.each_with_index do |person, index|
  # first person in array does not need an "OR" at the front
  the_or = index == 0 ? "" : " OR "
  # TODO make this statement more secure
  whereClause << "#{the_or}people.lastname = '#{person}'"
end
joins(:people).where(whereClause).length
```

2:

```
joins(:people).where({"people.lastname" => array})
```

Are either of the above methods secure by Rails standards?  It seems as though any sort of string could get passed into the query as it stands now.  Does anyone have any recommendations about how to get Rails to check the query before running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 is secure because Rails automatically sanitizes when it constructs a clause from a hash.

Rails will not sanitize the clause you pass in for method 1. (Indeed, Rails has no way of determining which part of the string `whereClause` is user input in need of sanitization and which was hard-coded and therefore exactly what you intended.)

You can see this if you set your console to output SQL from ActiveRecord activities:

```
> User.where(first_name: "first'name", last_name: "last'name")

User Load (166.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`first_name` = 'first\'name' AND `users`.`last_name` = 'last\'name'

> User.where("first_name = 'first'name' AND last_name = 'last'name'")

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (first_name = 'first'name' AND last_name = 'last'name')

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'name' AND last_name = 'last'name')' at line 1: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (first_name = 'first'name' AND last_name = 'last'name')
```

To answer your second question (how to make method 1 secure), you should do something like this:

```
> User.where("first_name = ? AND last_name = ?", "first'name", "last'name")

User Load (165.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (first_name = 'first\'name' AND last_name = 'last\'name')
```

As you can see the question marks are replaced in the resulting query by subsequent arguments to `where`, sanitized and in order.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1. Insecure

Method 2. Secure

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection